# html template with martini in golang

Tags: go, martini, go-html-template

I have problem with go, martini and how martini works with templates.

```
package main

import (
   "github.com/go-martini/martini"
   "github.com/martini-contrib/render"
)
type Page struct {
    Caption string
    Body    string
    Tmpl    string
}
func main() {
    webApp = martini.Classic()
    webApp.Get("/", indexHandler)
    webApp.Use(render.Renderer(render.Options{
      Directory:  "templates",
      Layout:     "layout",
      Extensions: []string{".tmpl", ".html"},
      Delims:     render.Delims{"{{", "}}"},
      Charset:    "UTF-8",
      IndentJSON: true}))
    webApp.Run()

}
func indexHandler(r render.Render) {
    var indexPage Page
    indexPage.Caption = "index"
    indexPage.Tmpl = "subIndex"
    r.HTML(http.StatusOK, "index", indexPage)
}
```

If I use in index.tmpl with fallowing code:

```
 <h2>Caption{{.Caption}}</h2>
{{ .Tmpl }}
```

// caption works, .Tmpl works and see subIndex as string )

If I use in index.tmpl with fallowing code:

```
<h2>Caption{{.Caption}}</h2>
{{ template .Tmpl }}
```

I get error unexpected "Tmpl" in template invocation
Same error message

```
 <h2>Caption{{.Caption}}</h2>
{{ $templateName := .Tmpl }}
{{ $templateName }}

{{ template $templateName }}
```

subIndex.tmpl is simple

```
 <h3>subindex</h3>
```

I have built program with go build, and stared it, when I open browsers with localhost:3000, i got errors which I have mentioned.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is it the capital t in Tmpl?

Comment: You use sourcePage for r.HTML but variables are in indexPage. Should be r.HTML(http.StatusOK, "index", indexPage)

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you had a full copy of the working code. I have to figure out what you're importing.

Comment: Also, you haven't said what command you ran and where you saw the error, just that there's an error somewhere when you do something.

Comment: In struct Page Tmpl is capital, in filename it's not. I have tried just to print tmpl with {{ .Templ }} in index.tmpl and that is working, but when i want to passit like name of template it not...

Comment: I have updated my original post. :)

Comment: From https://github.com/go-martini/martini
NOTE: The martini framework is no longer maintained.